# How to sort array of strings by eslint/prettier

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, prettier

I have array of keys and I would like to sort it alphabeticaly when I run eslint --fix/prettier. I guess something like this doesn't exist by default because it changes behavious of the code.

So my question is how could I create custom rule like that. Is it easier to do in eslint or prettier?

Answer (score 0):

A simple search of npm packages found this one for sorting arrays of strings by value:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-sort-array-values

Comment: please show how to use it for this question in your answer post.

Comment: Just follow the [config setup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-sort-array-values#usage). It's just a few lines for your eslint, not worth copying here.